# Does Presto SQL support recursive query using CTE just like SQL Server? e.g. employee hierarchy level

Tags: presto, trino

I want to write a recursive query using CTE in Presto to find Employee Hierarchy. Do Presto support recursive query?
When I write simple recursion as

`with cte as(select 1 n
           union all
           select cte.n+1 from cte where n<50)
select * from cte`

It gives error that

***Error running query: line 3:32: Table cte does not exist***

Answer (score 7):

**Current answer**

Recursive queries are supported in [Trino](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/1122), but [not PrestoDB](https://fburl.com/e97podgj) implementations of Presto.

**Old answer**

Presto grammar supports [`WITH RECURSIVE name AS ...`](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/70caaa2e53c1327abcabfcd5c30295a37ab3f555/presto-parser/src/main/antlr4/io/prestosql/sql/parser/SqlBase.g4#L123-L124), but [recursive WITH queries are not implemented](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/e27b09c5d478182778ae99fd017dbb2591d7dfca/presto-main/src/main/java/io/prestosql/sql/analyzer/StatementAnalyzer.java#L1994-L1996).

This is tracked as a feature request:
https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/1122

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(n) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 50)
SELECT * from cte
```

Error : `Recursion depth limit exceeded (10)`

adjust `max_recursion_depth`