# athena (presto) windowing function

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a dataset that I would like to deduplicate based on the time of arrival. I am familiar with the lag function but lag doesn't solve the problem here.

The process is that we partition by id and then start with the first row. If the time is within 60 seconds of this row, we assigned all those rows to this bucket. Following this, we move to the next row that is not assigned to a bucket yet. Similarly, we take all the rows that are within 60 seconds of this row and we repeat the process until we reach the end of the partition/and dataset.

At the end we just can easily filter for the first row within each id, desired grouping groups.

| id | time | desired grouping | desired outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | 0 | 1 | keep |
| one | 59 | 1 | remove |
| one | 62 | 2 | keep |
| one | 69 | 2 | remove |
| one | 121 | 2 | remove |
| two | 59 | 1 | keep |
| two | 63 | 1 | remove |
| two | 69 | 1 | remove |
| two | 88 | 1 | remove |
| three | 10 | 1 | keep |
| three | 70 | 2 | keep |
| four | 10 | 1 | keep |

I would greatly appreciate it if you have any suggestions on how to achieve this desired grouping.

Comment: This requires some kind of recursion, which I am afraid Presto does not support yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428322/does-presto-sql-support-recursive-query-using-cte-just-like-sql-server-e-g-emp

Comment: @GMB Athena 3rd engine version should be based on Trino, also I think this can be achieved without recursion by using pattern recognition approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Athena engine v3 is based on Trino which allows some (I would argue a bit convoluted at first glance) pattern detection via [`MATCH_RECOGNIZE`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/match-recognize.html#pattern-recognition-expressions) clause. If you are already using this engine version and it is available in Athena's Trino version then you can try using it. For example (I'm not fluent with this part of Trino, so maybe it can be written much better):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(id, time) as(
    values ('one', 0),
        ('one', 59),
        ('one', 62),
        ('one', 69),
        ('one', 121),
        ('two', 59),
        ('two', 63),
        ('two', 69),
        ('two', 88)
)

-- query
select *
from dataset
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
     PARTITION BY id
     ORDER BY time
     MEASURES
              A.time AS time
     ONE ROW PER MATCH
     AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
     PATTERN (A B+)
     DEFINE
              B AS time <= FIRST(time) + 60
     )
order by id, time;
```

Output:

| id | time |
| --- | --- |
| one | 0 |
| one | 62 |
| two | 59 |

Read and watch more:

- [Row pattern recognition with MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://trino.io/blog/2021/05/19/row_pattern_matching.html)
- [23: Trino looking for patterns](https://trino.io/episodes/23.html)

**UPD**

To handle new requirements changed the [pattern](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/match-recognize.html#row-pattern-syntax) (and fixed the condition):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(id, time) as(
    values ('1', 0),
        ('1', 59),
        ('1', 62),
        ('1', 69),
        ('1', 121),
        ('2', 59),
        ('2', 63),
        ('2', 69),
        ('2', 88),
        ('3',   10),
        ('3',   70),
        ('4',   10)
)

-- query
select *
from dataset
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
     PARTITION BY id
     ORDER BY time
     MEASURES
              A.time AS time
     ONE ROW PER MATCH
     AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
     PATTERN (A B*)
     DEFINE
              B AS time < FIRST(time) + 60
     )
order by id, time;
```

Output:

| id | time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 62 |
| 2 | 59 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 3 | 70 |
| 4 | 10 |

Comment: Thanks Guru, definitely didn't know about this but seems to be available in athena. Will have a look if it works

Comment: I have tested it and it seems to filter for only those that have an extra record in the window. I have also got other points without any duplicates at all or in the window, that I would like to keep. I have updated the question with some additional points.